# Can I pass Single Quote as Camel Query Parameter?

Tags: java, apache-camel, camel-sql

I'm trying to do a query like this:

```
SELECT * from Employee where First_Name between 'AA' and 'AK'
```

I'm using the camel sql component and passing a parameter through the header like this:

Query: `SELECT * from Employee where First_Name between :#headerParam`

Param: `AA' and 'AK`

I know that Camel's SQL component adds single quotes to the beginning and end of the parameters, and I'm looping through the between params, is there any way it won't remove the single quotes from my parameter?

Comment: why can't you do SELECT * from Employee where First_Name between :#headerParam1 and :#headerParam2 Is there a specific reason

Comment: I think Camel is using prepared statements, and one of the points of prepared statements is that you can't build up SQL queries via String concatenation: i.e. your parameters cannot contain SQL. I think you should separate the parameters as RamPrakash has suggested.

Comment: is it possible to double up the single quotes to escape characters? I know in SQL you can put two single quotes and it escapes the char. So AA'' and ''AK. I know nothing of camel sql, and this comes from knowledge of general SQL. Not sure it'll work but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: But @RamPrakesh is correct though, it should ideally be two parameters you pass not two with an AND through a parameter. That's sorta funky.

Comment: @mariob: If that what you suggest would work it would allow sql-injection. Ever thought about that?

Comment: Yes, I did use RamPrakash's suggestion to my solution and it works, I wanted to know if I could avoid having to declare 2 params, thanks everyone!